# Default path, localhost:{port}, just returning a blank page (simple)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

This should be a really, really simple one, I would assume. I'm throwing together a quick POC project in ASP.net -- something I've done plenty of times before. But this time, for whatever reason, the default landing page (url=localhost:portnumber doesn't show any content at all. However, requesting localhost:portnumber/home/index works fine. So it sounds like a route registering issue, but I didn't mess with any of that code. This issue really doesn't even matter, as it's just a POC and I'm fine just manually redirecting, but I just wanted to get this one answered for curiosity's sake.

Below is some relevant code:

From **global.asax:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and **Index.cshtml** for home is here, still with defaults for now:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>
```

and the **index action of home controller** (also left as default)

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
```

Edit: And here is **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
             <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                     <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The weird thing is that almost everything is left totally default. So it seems like I could expect default behavior, right? I'm sure I'm just missing something silly, but this is frustrating me nonetheless.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What does your layout page look like? (and do you have one?)

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Just using cassini(sp?), since it's a really basic POC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your project's web settings.  Alt+Enter on project file.  Set it to a specific page 'Home' and see if that fixes it.  You might be on Current Page.

Comment: Duh. That was it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: just weird that this is the first time it's defaulted to that

Comment: although actually, this isn't really solving the problem -- just masking it. For example, when I click the default "Home" link (which returns localhost:port) I get the same blank screen

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt If you set a breakpoint in the controller for the Index() view, are you able to step through it even when a blank page comes up?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Have you tried specifying a specific port instead of the random one generated by VS?

Comment: nope - but I've *never* done that, either. So idk why it would be a problem this time